# getting 'undefined' in slot values (Alexa using nodejs lambda)

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am passing two slots to the function. I am sending in the following xml.

Here is the request XML.
.....

```
  "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.[unique-value-here]",
    "intent": {
      "slots": {
        "chapter": "4",
        "shloka": "4"
      },
.....
```

**However when the code runs, I am getting undefined for the slots even thought they are there. 
Here is the code**

```
var intent = this.event.request.intent;
    console.log('slots are -->');
    console.log(intent.slots);
    var shloka = this.event.request.intent.slots.shloka.value;
    var chapter = this.event.request.intent.slots.chapter.value;
    console.log('chapter:' + chapter + ' shloka:' + shloka);
```

**Here is the console log**
     ...    slots are -->
     ...    { chapter: '4', shloka: '4' }
     ...    chapter:undefined shloka:undefined

I am not able to figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have to use `value` to access the value of `shloka` and `chapter`. Second, why access it by using `this.event.request.intent` two times, if you have the `intent` anyway inside a variable (Line 1 - `var intent = this.event.request.intent;`), in this case you can just write:

```
// Use this
var shloka = intent.slots.shloka;
var chapter = intent.slots.chapter;

// Instead of this
var shloka = this.event.request.intent.slots.shloka.value;
var chapter = this.event.request.intent.slots.chapter.value;
```

This should work as expected:

```
var intent = this.event.request.intent;
console.log('slots are -->');
console.log(intent.slots);
var shloka = intent.slots.shloka;
var chapter = intent.slots.chapter;
console.log('chapter:' + chapter + ' shloka:' + shloka);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. All amazon examples have .value to retrieve the slot. I wonder why it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.